# What's the list of commands for custom key bindings in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, xcode10

I want to have the full list of available commands for creating custom key bindings in the DETextKeyBindingSet.plist

My goal is to create more complex commands that print { } automatically for me

This is a few commands I found inside the file.

- moveToBeginningOfLine:,
- yank:
- deleteToEndOfLine:,
- insertNewline:,
- moveToBeginningOfLine:,

What's the full list so I can program more complex bindings?
Official API?

Comment: List at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsstandardkeybindingresponding

Comment: @Cœur how do you use the insertText func. I tried          <key>Insert Curly Braces</key>
        <string>insertText("{}"):, moveLeft:</string> but that won't work. I tried others combinations without success.

Comment: I do not know how to use those. I'm just aware that those are optional functions, so they may not all be implemented by Xcode.

Comment: @Cœur yep. it worked in previous XCode with insertText:, foo There is an old post on stack about it. I have tried it and it does not work. Sucks. Can't create my own code templates